# Async javascript call from Visualforce to REST service returns 403 forbidden (only in production)

Tags: visualforce, ajax, forcetk

I have a simple Visualforce page with a couple of input fields and a button (No controller being used here) that, when the button is clicked, sends a JSON payload to an Apex REST service. I am using the **forceTK** toolkit to make this ajax call.

This example works perfectly in multiple sandbox environments. However in Production, the ajax calls causes the server to respond with a 403 - Forbidden response. I have made no special configuration in the sandbox. The javascript code sample looks like this:

```
ftkClient.apexrest("/myRESTService/", 
    function(data) {},  
    function(data) {}, 
    'POST', 
    data,
    null,
    false);      
  }
```

myRESTService is an Apex class annotated like this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myRESTService/')
```

My question is:
 - What do I need to do to make this work in Production?

At this stage, I am not looking to use an alternative approach like Javascript Remoting. I would really like to fix this if I can.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you migrate profile permissions or set them afterwards? You can't execute the call if it's not on the profile.

Comment: @sfdcfox, sorry if I am sounding a bit confused. I have not configured or modified any specific permissions in any sandboxes - all I have done is create the required static resources for scripts, my REST class and my Visualforce page. What permissions would I need to migrate/set in production to make this work, and why? Thank you for responding!

Comment: The user who is using the page will need to have profile or permission set level permissions set for both the Visualforce page as well as the myRESTService apex class.

Comment: sfdcfox, Christian Carter - Thank you so much! That seems to have solved my problem. I will run a few more tests and will re-confirm. How do I mark your solutions/comments as accepted?